# Form element not sending its values

Tags: javascript

So I have a form:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="test.html">
    <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <input type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <button name="send" type="submit" class="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

and after the user submits the form, it is sent to test.html through POST method. And this is the code on test.html.

```
<div id="targetDiv"></div>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var first=$("#first").val();
    var last=$("#last").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var comments=$("#comments").val();
    var txt1="Welcome " +first+" "+last;
    var txt2="Your Email is " +email;
    var txt3="Your Message is "+ comments;
    $("#targetDiv").append(txt1+"<br>"+txt2+"<br>"+txt3);
</script>
```

but when the user submits, #targetDiv always prints out:

```
Welcome undefined undefined
Your Email is undefined
Your Message is undefined
```

Comment: Try GET instead POST

Comment: An HTML page cannot access posted values. You need to set up an actual server-side program to deal with form posts.

Comment: @Titus so do i put the js under the form? then how do i do the test.html?

Comment: @Tomalak so i need an actual server?

Comment: You can't post data to a `.html` file (you may be able to do this using a `GET` request). Also, you should set `name` values to your `input`s.

Comment: change the test file to .php file instead of html then use $_POST to get the data then show them

Comment: Yes, basically you need a server. I'm sure you have one available already and if not it's easy to install. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Tomalak mac el capitan

Comment: The answer you accepted shows a way of doing things without a server, but without a server you really don't need form posts, either. If you decide to set up a web server, there are many tutorials around the internet, this one seems rather complete https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/ (You don't need all of that to start, but most of what you will ever need is covered there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form and the div you are trying to append values to need to be in the same html file unless you are working with a server. Also give your submit an event listener to call all the code you already have. Like this:

```
$(".submit").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var first=$("#first").val();
  var last=$("#last").val();
  var email=$("#email").val();
  var comments=$("#comments").val();
  var txt1="Welcome " +first+" "+last;
  var txt2="Your Email is " +email;
  var txt3="Your Message is "+ comments;
  $("#targetDiv").append(txt1+"<br>"+txt2+"<br>"+txt3);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is indeed sending values to the server using a POST request. However, the page `test.html` is a different page from the page with the form, so the `<input>` elements no longer exist at that point.

You will need to write server-side code to handle the POST parameters and insert them into the `test.html` page.

Alternatively, you could send the parameters with a `GET` request, and inspect the `window.location.queryString` property to parse the values.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript or jquery is not a server side language .. use any serverside script like php,asp.

if you want to do the same using jquery use the following method..

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="test.html">
    <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <input type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <input  type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <button id="button" name="send" type="button" class="submit">SEND</button>
</form> 

<div id="targetDiv">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#button').click(function () {
    var first=$("#first").val();
    var last=$("#last").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();
    var comments=$("#comments").val();
    var txt1="Welcome " +first+" "+last;
    var txt2="Your Email is " +email;
    var txt3="Your Message is "+ comments;
    $("#targetDiv").append(txt1+"<br>"+txt2+"<br>"+txt3);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it inside the jQuerys document ready function and trigger the function when user clicks on the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".submit").on("click", function() {

      var first=$("#first").val();
      var last=$("#last").val();
      var email=$("#email").val();
      var comments=$("#comments").val();
      var txt1="Welcome " +first+" "+last;
      var txt2="Your Email is " +email;
      var txt3="Your Message is "+ comments;
      $("#targetDiv").append(txt1+"<br>"+txt2+"<br>"+txt3);
  });
});
```

Comment: This only works if you have `#targetDiv` on the same page, so you'll want to call `.preventDefault()` on the click event object: `.on("click", function (ev) { ev.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: This also doesn't send any data to the server, which may be required.